# Xamarin.Android Localization Resx Resources string to Android Resources String

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, localization, visual-studio-2019

I have Created a AppResource.Resx and and AppResource.da.resx  and i have also Resources string in String.XML with Value-da => String.XML

```
 AppResources.Culture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
                Java.Util.Locale.Default = new Java.Util.Locale("da", "DK");
                Resources.Configuration.Locale = Java.Util.Locale.Default;
                Resources.UpdateConfiguration(Resources.Configuration, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
                var sfs = Resources.GetText(Resource.String.AboutLabel);
                var dfdd = AppResources.AboutLabel;
                Finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.Class);
                StartActivity(intent);
                var dffdsadd = AppResources.AboutLabel;
                var fdsfdsafs = Resources.GetText(Resource.String.AboutLabel);
```

here is I'm Trying to set or update the Resources of android and these resources get from AppResource.resx file but not updating resources?
How i can bind AppResources string with android String so localization and value access?

Comment: You can follow MVVM patten (can use MVVMCross - Xamarin.Native) and bind the property to text control of Android and iOS using same resource. ||| Core ViewModel :- public string SharedAppResourceText { get; set; } = AppResources.SharedAppResourceValue; ||| Android :- <TextView local:MvxBind="Text SharedAppResourceText"/> ||| iOS :- set.Bind(TestLabel).For("Title").To(vm => vm.SharedAppResourceText);

Answer (score 1):

When you import files, translate files, export files, for use in your Xamarin mobile apps, you could use one of the following file formats:

- RESX files for Xamarin.Forms
- Localizable.strings files for the Xamarin.iOS native platform
- Android Strings files for the Xamarin.Android native platform

Do not bind AppResources string with android String so localization and value access. You could download the sample code from the link for reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows

Comment: You are right but we have share DAL between Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS.so therefore we want to share same resources between Android and IOS Native

Comment: iOS needs us to mention the localizations used in our Xamarin project in its Info.plist file. You could download the sample code for reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/usingresxlocalization/